# SAS: What is the fileref referring to in a DDE link?

Tags: excel, sas, dde

Can someone please explain what a statement like

```
filename fileref dde 'excel|system';
```

does within SAS?

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648774(v=vs.85).aspx), Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)

> sends messages between applications that share data and uses shared
>   memory to exchange data between applications.

This makes DDE sound like some sort of I/O stream.

Yet, the [DDE Syntax within SAS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/67962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0nfh32rqmc1xdn1e0rs1it8qy35.htm) requires a *fileref* within a `FILENAME` statement,  where a

> fileref is a valid fileref (as described in Referencing External
>   Files).

The [Referencing External Files](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/67962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n07buc7sg08fdrn1c1jmmr8hl78r.htm) then goes on to define a *fileref* as

> A fileref is a logical name associated with an external file.

What external file?

My naive understanding is that it opens some sort of communication channel between Excel and SAS, hence my want to call it a stream.  This has implications such as the above statement must be declared *after* Excel has been opened.

Comment: I'm sure you've come across this, but DDE isn't a recommended method anymore. ODS Excel as of SAS 9.4 is pretty decent and getting there in terms of functionality.

Comment: I'm looking for scalpel-like precision when importing data.  I want complete control over what I'm bringing in and how it's being brought in.  Although it's been a while since I did a 'literature review', I found that PROC IMPORT and LIBNAME simply don't provide that much control;  everything needs to be cleaned up after being imported.  A quick glance tells me that ODS Excel is only for exporting.  Am I mistaken and, regardless, can it provide me the extreme precision DDE offers?

Comment: If you want scalpel like precision, don't use Excel.

Comment: Verify how it handles formatted data vs the underlying data point. I can't recall the specifics but I recall this being an issue in imports. As @Joe has indicated, if you want control, a text file is a better method. DDE requires so much manual customization you may as well do the conversion manually anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's not a physical file involved in DDE.  Rather, as you note, it is a stream.  SAS and C are fairly similar in that sense; files really are more like devices.  There are plenty of other similar examples - the `pipe` device, for example, which allows you to interact with the system console as if it were a file.

What's really happening as far as I can tell behind the scenes, is that SAS is writing to the Global Atom Table, discussed by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649053(v=vs.85).aspx).  That causes a message to be broadcast that Excel will read and react to.

Comment: SAS might treat it as a stream, but the DDE protocol isn't a stream - it operates in shared memory and allows random access.